# Suddenly stopped working

Tags: texstudio

Was using TexStudio with I think MixTex or something as the source of all the LaTeX coding stuff.. anyway I was using it fine, and had a working document that would produce a working pdf, until suddenly, without changing the input whatsoever or entering any other programs, it stops working and spits out the error message:

`pdflatexdef.exe: The script interpreter could not be found.
pdflatexdef.exe: Data: scriptInterpreter="perl.exe"`

I'm on Windows 10 so I should probably blame that; should I just download MixTex again or should I do something else simpler or does someone know why what just happened just happened?

Comment: What did you did with your computer between when the error began to occur and when everything worked?

Comment: Why are you trying to use pdflatexdef? (Instead of pdflatex)?

Comment: I did nothing outside of the program between it working fine and the error coming up, I was able to restore the input to exactly as it was before the input came up without working outside of the program

Comment: I'm trying reinstalling MikTex and seeing if that might make a difference. Also I'll check I'm not accidentally using pdflatexdef instead of pdflatex or something

Comment: just checked and the setting was at pdfTex; maybe that was the issue?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Configure TeXstudio]

As @Ulrike Fischer already mentioned, have a look at Options - Configure TeXstudio and point to the path where pdflatex.exe resides on your computer. This is C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin in my case.